# Remove multiple <p> tag to single tag

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace all:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

with

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

using regex how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Do not combine HTML with regex.

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a well bounded case you can use `preg_replace()` to achieve that with:

RegEx: `(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\s*)+`
Replacement: `\1`

Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/vB5sZ0

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ka when i used <p>asdasdasd</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> this senerio nothing change .something wrong with this regex.

Answer (score 0):

Despite some comment correctly pointing out that parsing HTML using regex's is dangerous, in controlled environments or when parsing isn't necessary (your case I believe, as you seem to only want to replace some stuff) I consider it to be the most optimal solution (despite not being perfect).

Either way, if I understood your question correctly you want to replace multiple duplicates with a single instance? In that case it can be simply achieved by a regex along the lines of:

```
 "<br><br>a<br><br><br>b".replace(/(<br>){2,}/g, '<br>');
```

That example is in javascript (as I could test it out from the browser console), but the regex and basic concept is the same in php: you match two or more instances of the string you're interested in and replace it with a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an **html parser** instead of regex.

But if the `p` tag is not nested you can use this regex

```
/<p>&nbsp;</p>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
"<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>"

    .replace(/(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n?)+/, "<p>&nbsp;</p>");
```

Comment: oh sorry, i though this was tagged javascript !

Comment: anyway, `(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n?)+` here is your regex ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, use `str_replace`.

Replace all `<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>` with one and do it until no change is made.

```
$input2 = $input_text;
$end = false;

while(!$end){
  $temp_text=str_replace("<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>","<p>&nbsp;</p>", $input2);
  if($temp_text == $input2){
    $end = true;
    }
  else{
    $input2 = $temp_text;
  }
}
```

In the line with `str_replace()` you might need to add a new line character (`\n`) and/or line feed (`\r`).